# Display and store information from mysql table

Tags: javascript, html, mysql

I am currently learning PHP and MySQL so I hope this makes sense;
I have a table called products and it has 3 columns "Product", "Buy" and "sell" and it has a bunch of rows with data.

How would I display this all in a table on my website preferably in a table of sorts. It doesn't have to look nice its just for a practice exercise.

Comment: You would love having [**IBM's published tutorial _"Creating dynamic Web sites with PHP and MySQL"_ online**](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/tutorials/l-php/)

Comment: I will give that a read!